# Javascript object | grouping | native functions

Tags: javascript, html

### my input

```js
const orders = [
  {
    category: "Apparel",
    type: "Casual Shirts",
    sold: 15
  },
  {
    category: "Apparel",
    type: "Casual Trousers",
    sold: 10
  },
  {
    category: "Footwear",
    type: "Sports Shoes",
    sold: 9
  },
  {
    category: "Footwear",
    type: "Sports Shoes",
    sold: 11
  },
  {
    category: "Accessory",
    type: "Fitness Gadget",
    sold: 3
  },
  {
    category: "Apparel",
    type: "Casual Shirts",
    sold: 9
  }
];
```

above is my input, I want to output something like below:

```js
console.log({
  Apparel: [
    {
      type: "Casual Shirts",
      totalSold: 24
    },
    {
      type: "Casual Trousers",
      totalSold: 10
    }
  ],
  Footwear: [
    {
      type: "Sports Shoes",
      totalSold: 20
    }
  ],
  Accessory: [
    {
      type: "Fitness Gadget",
      totalSold: 3
    }
  ]
});
```

Have tried something like below which wont give expected output

```js
var temp = [];

orders.forEach((value)=>{
  if(temp.indexOf(value.category)<0){
    temp.push({'category':value.category,'sold':value.sold})
    
  } else {
    temp[temp.indexOf(value.category)].sold += value.sold;
  }
})

console.log(temp)
```

Comment: no, i have already tried this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to group based on `category` and `type` in an object accumulator and then convert `type` to an array.

```js
const orders = [ { category: "Apparel", type: "Casual Shirts", sold: 15 }, { category: "Apparel", type: "Casual Trousers", sold: 10 }, { category: "Footwear", type: "Sports Shoes", sold: 9 }, { category: "Footwear", type: "Sports Shoes", sold: 11 }, { category: "Accessory", type: "Fitness Gadget", sold: 3 }, { category: "Apparel", type: "Casual Shirts", sold: 9 } ],
      result = orders.reduce((r, {category, type, sold}) => {
        r[category] ??= {[type]: null};
        r[category][type] ??= {type, totalSold: 0};
        r[category][type].totalSold += sold;
        return r;
      },{}),
      output = Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(result)
        .map(([key, value]) => [key, Object.values(value)])
      );
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

A good concise way to solve it is to use `reduce()` as others have posted - but here is an alternative. It is more the "classic" way to solve a problem like this. It is actually less efficient and slower! But I would argue more readable at a glance.

```
const orders = [ { category: "Apparel", type: "Casual Shirts", sold: 15 }, { category: "Apparel", type: "Casual Trousers", sold: 10 }, { category: "Footwear", type: "Sports Shoes", sold: 9 }, { category: "Footwear", type: "Sports Shoes", sold: 11 }, { category: "Accessory", type: "Fitness Gadget", sold: 3 }, { category: "Apparel", type: "Casual Shirts", sold: 9 } ];
const groupByCategory = (arr) => {
    const groups = {};
    for (const item of arr) {
        const { category, type, sold } = item;
        if (!groups[category]) {
            groups[category] = {};
        } 
        if (!groups[category][type]) {
            groups[category][type] = {
                type,
                totalSold: sold
            }
        } else {
            groups[category][type].totalSold += sold;
        }
    }

    // Convert the sub-nodes to array.
    const result = {};
    for (const category of Object.keys(groups)) {
        result[category] = [];
        for (const type of Object.values(groups[category])) {
            result[category].push(type);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(groupByCategory(orders));
```